# Mocking getpass using patch

Tags: python

I want to write a test for a function that gets the password from user, using prompt:

```
from getpass import getpass
....
    getpass(Password)
```

In the test class:

```
import getpass

    @patch('getpass.getpass')
    def test_func(self, mock_getpass_func):
      ....
      mock_getpass_func.return_value = 'mockpassword'
      ....
```

But when I run the test, it throws :

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/getpass.py", line 91, in unix_getpass
    passwd = fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/getpass.py", line 126, in fallback_getpass
    return _raw_input(prompt, stream)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/getpass.py", line 148, in _raw_input
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Why doesn't it simply mock the function and its return value? How should I mock it?

Comment: can we see how you define the mock

Comment: I corrected my post. I import `getpass` and patch its `getpass` function.

Comment: Mock the function where you are using it: `@patch('your_module.getpass')`.

Comment: You patch where it's *used*, not where it's *defined*.